# Wrap long url line in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I've read the various posts on this, but I still haven't found a solution. Here's some example code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

urlfile<-'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blakeobeans/Predicting-Service-Calls/master/Data/nc.csv'
dates<-read.csv(urlfile, header=FALSE)
dates$V1 <- mdy(dates$V1)
dates <- dates %>%
    rename("data.time" = V1) %>%
    filter("2017-10-01" >= data.time & data.time >= "2017-06-01") %>%
    group_by(data.time) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
```

When I output to the pdf...

[image]

The same thing happens if I have notes in the code running out of the grey bar.

I've tried using the following line of code at the beginning:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60),tidy=TRUE)
```

But that doesn't help.

Comment: I remember that code blocks in rmd are not wrapped. [This issue is similar to your problem](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/646) but it seems there's not an easy fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem when putting package on CRAN (they give a note if `Rd` file line exceeds 90 characters (*NOTE: lines wider than 90 characters*)). One of the arguments to my function was url to a `github` dataset. Solution was to split url into separate arguments. For example:

```
urlRemote  <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/"
pathGithub <- "blakeobeans/Predicting-Service-Calls/master/Data/"
fileName   <- "nc.csv"
```

And you can use it in your code like this:

```
paste0(urlRemote, pathGithub, fileName) %>%
    read.csv(header = FALSE)
```

This solution has an advantage when you want to use multiple files from the same repository as you can use `paste0(urlRemote, pathGithub, fileName1)`, `paste0(urlRemote, pathGithub, fileName2)`, etc.